# How to use Range.Value to read Excel cell containing accented letters?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of files in Excel that I need to automate and cannot do that for files with names containing accented letters.
For instance:
When Excel cell contains a string: RADOŚĆOPORANKU.txt
The cell content read by Range.Value is RADOSCOPORANKU.txt, the accented letters were converted, i.e. Ś to S and Ć to C.
Dir(string) of course cannot find that file.

My simple test with 2 files located in the following directory:
D:\Andre\Szarada\For Szarada\Awaiting\

Algebraf NOCSIERPNIOWA.xlsx in A65 and 
Algebraf RADOŚĆOPORANKU.xlsx in A66
(Note: only the uppercase text is in the cells A65 and A 66)

```
Sub test()
    Dim str, filename As String
    str = Range("A65").Value
    filename = "D:\Andre\Szarada\For Szarada\Awaiting\Algebraf " & str & ".xlsx"
    MsgBox Dir(filename)
End Sub
```

It works fine for A65 returning filename, it returns "" for A66 not finding the file with accented letters.
Equally, if I remove the accented letters for both the A66 cell and the actual file name in the directory it works fine as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read about `FileSystemObject`.  And also check out the various QA's in this forum on that same topic.

Comment: Can you point me to to a QA that provides an answer? I searched and searched and all I can find is the reverse, how to get rid of accented letters not what VBA method to use to read (Polish) accented letters that are in Excel into a VBA string.

Comment: Search the site for `DIR Unicode`

Comment: It seems that I did not do a good job of explaining. It is not the Dir that fails it is that the file name I ask Dir to look for has the accented letters stripped by Range.Value. So of course Dir does not find the file which name has those accented letters. All I want is to find out how to read an Excel cell that has Polish accented letters without the accents being stripped.

Comment: Your problem is elsewhere. `Range.Value` has no issue with any Unicode characters and does not "strip" or convert them.

Comment: I'm sorry but it does for me. Please just do the simple test: String = range("cellAddr").Value where the cell contains either Ś or Ć accented letter and analyse the String. If, in fact your String does contain those accented chrs and not S and C as I get, please let me know what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: Wrong test.  Do something like `Range("A2") = Range("A1") where `A1` contains string with accented letters.  It will copy properly.  Your mistake is that the VBA Editor cannot "show" accented letters. Try `str = [A1] :  [A2]= str` and you will see the accents preserved.

Comment: I know that it works from Excel to Excel as you pointed out. I need to get a file name from Excel and then move that file to a different directory via VBA. I read the file name (that has accented letters) into a string, look in which directory it exists via Dir and that is where it fails. DIr says no such file because the file name from Excel has no accented letters while the file in its directory does.

Comment: If I do exactly the same with a file name in Excel without accented letters it all works, Dir finds where it is and I can move it via fso.MoveFile. So please try that simple test and see if your String does indeed retain the accents.

Comment: Again, your problem is not with `Range.Value`. Your problem is with `Dir`. When `Dir` returns the string containing the filename, `Dir` strips out the accented characters.

Comment: My simple test with 2 files in the directory:
D:\Andre\Szarada\For Szarada\Awaiting\
Algebraf NOCSIERPNIOWA.xlsx
in A65
Algebraf RADOŚĆOPORANKU.xlsx
in A66

Sub test()
 Dim str, filename As String
 str = Range("A65").Value
 filename = "D:\Andre\Szarada\For Szarada\Awaiting\Algebraf " & str & ".xlsx"
 MsgBox Dir(filename)
End Sub

It works for A65 (no accented letters) returning filename, it returns "" for A66 (accented letters)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the board and I don't know how to format a comment correctly.

Comment: Don't put code in a comment.  Edit your question to add the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to do is move a file from one folder to another, use the `FileSystemObject`

For example:

**A1**

[image]

```
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'  or, if this for distribution, convert to late-binding

Option Explicit
Sub fileMover()
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim FI As File, FO As File
    Dim sSrc As String, sDest As String
    Const sBasePath As String = "D:\Users\Ron\Desktop\"

sSrc = sBasePath & [A1] & ".txt"
sDest = sBasePath & "Temp\" & [A1] & ".txt"

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject

FSO.MoveFile sSrc, sDest

End Sub
```

In "pure" VBA you could use the `Name` function, but limited testing here show that it, too, has problems with special characters, as does `MsgBox`

Comment: Thanks Ron, that was my experience too. Without trying to locate the file's directory via Dir, but specifying it, fso.MoveFile fails not being able to find the file which name contains accented letters. So it seems that it cannot be done in VBA without removing the accented letters from the file name first?

Comment: @AndreSocha Huh? Moving the file worked perfectly OK using that code, and the accents were retained in the destination file.

Comment: And you were right, it's not Range.Value, it is that neither Dir nor fso.MoveFile seems to be able to handle accented letters correctly.

Comment: @AndreSocha The code I provided handled the accented characters with no problem.

Comment: Sorry Ron, I misunderstood your comment. Yes, your code works, thank you. Any suggestion how I can confirm if the file exists in a directory? Using Dir in your code also returns "" for the accented file.

Comment: Silly of me fso.FileExists(sSrc) does work with the file. Thank you for all your help Ron, I really appreciate it.